# How to determine week of a quarter in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find the **Week of a Quarter** from a sql date in Oracle.

I tried below query to find the year, quarter and week.
But the week field gives the 'Week of the month' not the 'Week of the quarter'

> select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')|| '-Q' || to_char(sysdate, 'Q') || '-W' || >to_char(sysdate, 'w')  as "Current Time"
>   from dual;

Above query returns '2016-Q2-W3' as the date falls in the 3rd week of the month.

Say sysdate is '17th June, 2016'
I am expecting result as

> 2016-Q2-**W12**

My Week range is (Sunday - Saturday)

Since the '17th June, 2016' comes under 12th week of the quarter, it should be W12.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your current query can be simplified to: `select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-"Q"Q-"W"w') as "Current Time" from dual;`

Comment: `SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'Q' ) FROM DUAL` gives `2016-04-01` which is a Friday. Does `2016-Q2-W1` run from Friday - Thursday? Or does it run Monday - Sunday? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the week (Sunday - Saturday) of the quarter:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY-"Q"Q-"W"' )
     || ( 7 + TRUNC( SYSDATE + 1, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'Q' ) + 1, 'IW' ) ) / 7;
         AS "Current Time"
FROM DUAL
```

**Explanation**:

- You can find the Sunday which was either on-or-just-before a given date using `NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( date_value ), 'SUNDAY' ) - 7` (which is dependant on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting) or `TRUNC( date_value + 1, 'IW' ) - 1` (which is shorter and not dependant on any settings).
- `TRUNC( date_value, 'Q' )` gives the date of the first day of the quarter containing the `value` date (i.e. either 1st January, 1st April, 1st July or 1st October).
- Putting the two together, the Sunday on-or-just-before the first day of the quarter is given by `TRUNC( TRUNC( date_value, 'Q' ) + 1, 'IW' ) - 1`
- Therefore, the number of days between the Sunday on-or-just-before the start of the quarter and the Sunday on-or-just-before a given date is: `( TRUNC( date_value + 1, 'IW' ) - 1 ) - ( TRUNC( TRUNC( date_value, 'Q' ) + 1, 'IW' ) - 1 )` - which can be simplified by cancelling the `-1` terms.
- The number of weeks difference is just that number divided by 7 (but gives a 0-indexed value and you want the week number of the quarter to be 1-indexed; you either add 1 week to the result or, prior to doing the division, add 7 days).

Comment: Explanation please. 

Also I expect '2016-Q2-W13' for the date '19th June 2016'. Your solution gives 'W12' till 23rd June.

Comment: `SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'Q' ) FROM DUAL` gives `2016-04-01` which is a Friday. Does `2016-Q2-W1` run from Friday - Thursday? Or does it run Monday - Sunday? Or something else?