# Week of quarter - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How I can get week of quarter using Oracle SQL? I get week of month and week of year using simple function:

```
WITH SYSDATE_TABLE AS (
    SELECT to_date('01-06-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') as date_dt
    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    to_char(DATE_DT,'W') as WEEK_OF_MONTH,
    to_char(to_date(DATE_DT),'WW') as WEEK_OF_YEAR
FROM
    SYSDATE_TABLE;
```

I get month of quarter using `MOD` function:

```
(CASE mod(to_number(to_char(DATE_DT, 'MM')), 3)
    WHEN 0 THEN 3
    WHEN 1 THEN 1
    WHEN 2 THEN 2
END) AS MONTH_OF_QUARTER
```

But I don't know how I can get week of quarter. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine week of a quarter in Oracle query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890973/how-to-determine-week-of-a-quarter-in-oracle-query)

Comment: What do you consider as "week of quarter", i.e. when does it start? Always on Monday (like ISO-8601, resp. `TO_CHAR(..., 'IW')`) or the first day of quarter or the weekday of 1st of January (as for `TO_CHAR(..., 'WW')`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select 1 + TO_CHAR(DATE_DT, 'WW') - TO_CHAR(TRUNC(DATE_DT, 'Q'), 'WW')
from SYSDATE_TABLE;
```

According to your explanation: *First seven days of every quarter is first week. The next seven days is second week etc.* you could try this one:

```
select 1 + TRUNC( (DATE_DT - TRUNC(DATE_DT, 'Q')) / 7 )
from SYSDATE_TABLE;
```

Comment: I tested your solution more precisely and I think there is a bug. For example, `01-07-2015` is the first day of third quarter of the year and the code gives good result - `1` (first week of quarter). `02-07-2015` is the first week of quarter too, but the code gives result `2`. You can see this here: https://imgur.com/a/xkxzg I tried to solve this problem but I have no idea how I can do this. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: That was the question in my comment: What do you consider as "week of quarter"? Since you did not provide an answer I just made an assumption.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. By "week of quarter" I mean simple numbering days in quarter. It is like "week of month" (which I made this way - `to_char(DATE_DT, 'W')`), but for quarter. First seven days of every quarter is first week. The next seven days is second week etc. I know it is not really clear explonation, but I hope you know what I mean.